# deleting multiple files with .ksh script

Tags: ftp, ksh, aix

Right now I have a  .ksh ftp  function that deletes a file from an FTP site.  It takes the site info and the file name and deletes the file off the FTP site.

```
doftp(){   
ftp -vni <<STOP
    open $1
    user $2 $3
    binary\
    cd $5
    delete $6
    STOP
    }
```

The function's only shortcoming is that if you need to delete multiple files off server it makes a new connection every time.  I would like to speed things up a bit and delete multiple files within the same connection.  I tried something like this with $6 being an array of files to delete:

```
 deldoftp(){
    ftp -vni <<STOP
    counter=0 
    for s in ${6[@]}; do
    counter++
    if [counter=1]
    then 
    open $1
    user $2 $3
     binary\
    cd $5
    elif [counter <= 50]
   then
    delete $s
    else
    STOP
    counter=0
    fi 
    done
```

I have not gotten this code to work.  Is this due to syntax errors or is ksh not designed to work this way?

Comment: It has been suggested to use the lftp command, however that is not installed on the server at this time.  We are pushing for it though..

Comment: You can set vars $1-$5 to other vars and use shift. Then try something with $*. Perhaps generate all del commands before starting ftp and redirect the complete script.

Comment: Lines before STOP (should be without indentation) will be interpreted by ftp, not the ksh.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following approach: inside the function you send ftp commands to standard input of a piped ftp process:

```
function doftp {
    # in ksh functions "typeset" declares local variables
    typeset host=$1
    shift
    typeset user=$1
    shift
    typeset pass=$1
    shift
    typeset dir=$1
    shift
    (
        # printed text is send as input of the ftp process
        print "open $host"
        print -R "user $user $pass" # -R to prevent backslash interpretation
        print "binary"
        print "cd $dir"
        print "pwd"
        # $1 $2 ... are the files to delete
        for file in "$@"
        do
            print "rm  $file"
        done 
    ) | ftp -vni
}
```